# Надо ли использовать AtomicReference, если общие данные только для чтения?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть список запущенных потоков:

```
private final List<Thread> monsters;
```

Есть поле которое отвечает за индикацию конца всех потоков в списке:

```
private final AtomicBoolean endGame = new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

В том же классе у меня поток который мониторит живы ли потоки в списке, раз в секунду:

```
private void theAndGame() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!endGame.get()) {
                for (Thread monster: monsters) {
                    if (monster.isAlive()) {
                        endGame.set(true);
                    }
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Кроме этого потока никто `endGame` не изменяет.

Вопрос: надо ли в такой ситуации оборачивать `List<Thread> monsters` в `AtomicReference`? Или нет?

Comment: Вам и `AtomicBoolean` не нужен. Достаточно `volatile boolean`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет. Надо сделать Getter-метод типа `getMonsters()`, в котором брать (в простейшем случае) блокировку по `monsters`, а потом возвращать `return new ArrayList(monsters)` дабы не словить случайно `ConcurrentModificationException`.